# How to say my bike is running out of air and needs to be filled with air

Tags: phrase-requests

I'd appreciate if you tell me what is the right way to say my bike/motorbike/car's tire is running out of air and needs to be filled with air again in English.

Comment: It might be said to be "going flat".

Comment: @AndrewLeach And how would you say it needs to be refilled?

Comment: "It's going flat and I need to get it pumped up" *or* "...and I need to pump it up."

Comment: Simply saying "need air" and pointing at the vehicle would get the point across in most cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We say the [tire pressure](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tyre-pressure) is low. Also, if the tire is punctured, we say it is a "flat" or is "deflated."

To get the air into the tire we say that we need to put air into it, pump air into it, inflate or fill it.

Comment: And how would you say it needs to be refilled?

Comment: @Mori (while bicycling) "We have to stop at that service station; I need some air."

Answer (score 9):

In the UK, it's common to say a tyre (note the spelling!) is ***going flat.***

If it needs to be refilled, a common expression might be "It's going flat and I need to get it pumped up" *or* "...and I need ***to pump it up***".

We don't normally mention "air" explicitly, because it's a given that tyres are supposed to be full of air under pressure. And we use *pump* because — despite the ubiquity of garage air lines — the mental image is of one of these:

[image: Footpump]

[Screwfix](http://www.screwfix.com/p/double-barrel-foot-pump/6875H)

Comment: *Going flat* is pretty common in AmE also, in my experience. I also hear *pump it up* but I think *fill it up* might be more common. A garage air line is just as much a pump as the item in the image. It is just powered by electricity rather than muscles.

Answer (score 3):

You can say it's *flat*, *deflated*, in need of *inflating* or *inflation*, *low*, *low on air*, *needs to be pumped up*, *needs a pump*, *needs filling*, or *the pressure/tire pressure is low*.